# File Stream Handling in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a Web Application in which I am using **asp:FileUpload** Control to upload user `XSD` and reading its content(actually not uploading the XML Schema) using following Statement in a Click button function

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileUploadControlName.FileContent))
```

this reader object is used in `Click` button function to read `XMLSchema` and thus I generate collection on basis of that.

I just wanted to know is there any way to use this `StreamReader` object again so that I can handle the manipulation on other control action in Web-Application.

Means can there be a way to write the reader into `Memorystream` and reuse the `MemoryStream`.

Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: You want to continue the reader object itself, or just the data that has been read?

Comment: I know that by "using" statement the reader object will be disposed I m concerned with data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `using` the SteamReader will be disposed after the block ends, but not the stream itself. You can store the stream in a Session variable and reuse it like that, but I suggest you keep in mind to clear the Session variable. You can use MemoryStream or you can move the file to e TEMP location and store the file location in a Session variable. I would go with that option.

Comment: I used your Second Approach to move file to a Temporary Location and store the File location in Session. It worked .. Thanks Tomislav..

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse MemoryStream by setting the `Position` property to 0.

Example:

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
// later... after we read stuff
s.Position = 0;
```

And if you want to reuse the same object trough the application then you can use a Session variable. Then when you need to reuse it just set position to 0 again and read it with `StreamReader`.